# C# LINQ - Prop string has value of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

As it's described in title I'm getting somehow like list which contains oblivously list of strings?

How come?

Here is my query:

```
var productChangesUpdate = await _dbContext.ProductUpdates.Where(x => x.ProductId == ProductId)
                          .Select(x => new ProductChangeDto
                          {
                              Id = x.Id,
                              Title = x.Title,
                              Price = x.Price,
                              Date = x.CreatedDate,
                              ResponsiblePerson = x.ProductDeploy.ProductDeployResponsiblePersons.Select(x => x.User.FirstName + x.User.LastName).ToString()
                          }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Issue is that `ResponsiblePerson` value is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] instead of Full name..

What's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: It's a list (you call select on it). Then on that list you call `ToString()` which for most classes just prints their type. If you only want the name of the first person in that list you could do something like `FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `List.` You must use something similar to FirstOrDefaultAsync() or SingleOrDefaultAsync() in your case.

```
var productChangesUpdate = await _dbContext.ProductUpdates.Where(x => x.ProductId == ProductId)
                          .Select(x => new ProductChangeDto
                          {
                              Id = x.Id,
                              Title = x.Title,
                              Price = x.Price,
                              Date = x.CreatedDate,
                              ResponsiblePerson = x.ProductDeploy.ProductDeployResponsiblePersons.Select(x => x.User.FirstName + x.User.LastName).ToString()
                          }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```